# What to do with question with compiler warnings/errors due to copy & paste error

Tags: discussion, specific-question, broken-code

Unfortunately [in this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115680/simple-string-compression-reloaded) I posted some broken code due a copy-n-paste mistake without realizing. I've contemplated closing it but two answers have picked up on it and they also suggest other things beyond just pointing out the bugs. So I'm not sure if it might be better to just leave it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only realized *after the fact* and *after receiving answers* that the code you had posted was broken, and it wasn't clearly-enough broken to be pointed out and closed as *broken code* at a glance.

I'd just let it go, and suggest to post a new question with the correct code, modified with whatever other recommendations you received from answers.

In other words, pretend it never happened, and post a follow-up! :)

---

If you had realized the error *before* receiving answers, you could have edited the correct code into the question; someone could have pointed out the bugs in a comment, and/or voted to close as broken code - still then, the correct thing to do would have been to edit with the working code, because the purpose of putting a question "on hold" is to block answers that would be invalidated by fixing the code.

Comment: I already did :D